# Python: Difference Between Two Uses of np.append

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to explain why I want to do this but...why does this code

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
d = np.empty((0, 4))
d = np.append(d,[x],axis=0)
x[0]=8
d = np.append(d,[x],axis=0)
```

give me this

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 8.,  2.,  3.,  4.]])
```

while this code

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
d = np.empty((0, 4))
d = np.append(d,[x],axis=0)
x = d[0,]
x[0]=8
d = np.append(d,[x],axis=0)
```

gives me this?

```
array([[ 8.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 8.,  2.,  3.,  4.]])
```

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with append but rather the assignment (bindings) of numpy arrays as pointers to the same location in memory.

Consider the following example

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = x
y[0] = 8
print(x)
```

One would expect that since one did not
modify the array `x`, that the print statement
would yield the output `[1,2,3,4]` but in fact
the real output is `[8,2,3,4]`. The arrays `x` and `y`
are indistinguishable because they are pointers and
via the assignment `y=x` they point to the same address
of memory.

I assume that in your example, pointers became shared with
the command `x=d[0,]`.

See https://ecco-v4-python-tutorial.readthedocs.io/ECCO_v4_Operating_on_Numpy_Arrays.html for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: Thank you so much!